# Error Compiling MEAN.io webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have forked and started a project with [MEAN.io](http://mean.io) but my webpack compilation started to fail. This is the error I get. I know it says that some unexpected token ) is found somewhere. But the thing is that I have checked all my files and they look ok. Event the IDE (Intellij) tells me all the files are well formed. So I think this error is  something else.

In case you want to have a look at my files, [here they are](https://gist.github.com/pmenichelli/1578593b333fb9d866ddb13bbdd0fccc).

Thanks!!

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

  - lodash.js:14843
    [mean.io]/[lodash]/lodash.js:14843:16

  - lodash.js:494 apply
    [mean.io]/[lodash]/lodash.js:494:27

  - lodash.js:15227
    [mean.io]/[lodash]/lodash.js:15227:16

  - lodash.js:496 apply
    [mean.io]/[lodash]/lodash.js:496:27

  - lodash.js:6600
    [mean.io]/[lodash]/lodash.js:6600:16

  - lodash.js:14842 Function.template
    [mean.io]/[lodash]/lodash.js:14842:20


  - SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

  - compiler.js:76
    [mean.io]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16

  - Compiler.js:296 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:296:10

  - Compiler.js:499
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:499:13

  - Tapable.js:202 next
    [mean.io]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:202:11

  - CachePlugin.js:62 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:62:5

  - Tapable.js:206 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [mean.io]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:206:13

  - Compiler.js:496
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:496:10

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [mean.io]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:649 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:649:19

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [mean.io]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:640 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:640:11

  - Tapable.js:202 next
    [mean.io]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:202:11

  - UglifyJsPlugin.js:230 Compilation.compilation.plugin
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin.js:230:5

  - Tapable.js:206 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [mean.io]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:206:13

  - Compilation.js:635 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:635:10

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [mean.io]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:631 sealPart2
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:631:9

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [mean.io]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:579 Compilation.seal
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:579:8

  - Compiler.js:493
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:493:16

  - Tapable.js:289
    [mean.io]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:289:11

  - Compilation.js:481 _addModuleChain
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:481:11

  - Compilation.js:452 processModuleDependencies.err
    [mean.io]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:452:13

  - next_tick.js:73 _combinedTickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7

  - next_tick.js:104 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9


Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    [/EZv] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.hbs 785 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
            factory:27ms building:21ms = 48ms

    ERROR in ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.hbs
    Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
        at /Users/pablo/workspace/test-projects/mean.io/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:14843:16
        at apply (/Users/pablo/workspace/test-projects/mean.io/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:494:27)
        at /Users/pablo/workspace/test-projects/mean.io/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:15227:16
        at apply (/Users/pablo/workspace/test-projects/mean.io/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:496:27)
        at /Users/pablo/workspace/test-projects/mean.io/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:6600:16
        at Function.template (/Users/pablo/workspace/test-projects/mean.io/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:14842:20)
        at Object.module.exports (/Users/pablo/workspace/test-projects/mean.io/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js:32:20)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! landings-leadaki@1.0.0 webpack: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "config/webpack.prod.js" "--progress" "--profile" "--bail"`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the landings-leadaki@1.0.0 webpack script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pablo/.npm/_logs/2017-10-15T15_18_54_411Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! landings-leadaki@1.0.0 build:prod: `npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the landings-leadaki@1.0.0 build:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pablo/.npm/_logs/2017-10-15T15_18_54_451Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found it, can't believe I didn't see this.
In my index.hbs file, I accidentally deleted the closing curly brace of and EJS 'if' statement

```
<% if (webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags) { %>
  <!-- Configured Head Tags  -->
  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
<% } %>
```

So it seems that although I use handlebars, the HtmlWebpackPlugin internally uses EJS templating and tries to parse it. And that was the unexpected token that was missing.